# check input for a value and print something

Tags: java, while-loop

I post the original problem below. I got the most part right, but I don't know how to check if the first number entered is negative and print "bad input". Can any one help me.

Write a program that begins by reading in a series of positive integers on a single line of input and then computes and prints the product of those integers. Integers are accepted and multiplied until the user enters an integer less than 1. This final number is not part of the product. Then, the program prints the product. If the first entered number is negative or 0, the program must print “Bad input.” and terminate immediately.

Next, the program determines and prints the prime factorization of the product, listing the factors in increasing order. If a prime number is not a factor of the product, then it must not appear in the factorization. Sample runs are given below. Note that if the power of a prime is 1, then that 1 must appear in the answer.

Here is my code:

```
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter integers:");
    int product = 1;
    int num = 0;
    while (input.hasNextInt()) {
        num = input.nextInt();
        if (num < 1)
            break;
        product *= num;
    }
    System.out.println("Product: " + product);
    int f = 2;
    while (product >= f) {
        int count = 0;
        while (product % f == 0) {
            count++;
            product = product / f;
        }
        if (count > 0)
            System.out.print(f + "^" + count + " ");
        f++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do your own homework.

Answer (score 0):

Without giving you all the answers... keep track of which one is the first one. If it is the first one, check the value of it (see if it's 0 or less than 0) and if it is, print the error and end the program.

Answer (score 0):

Before your loop start reading input , read the first integer and do your logic

```
   int product = 1;
int num = 0;
  num = input.nextInt();
   if(num <1) {
      System.out.println("bad number");
       return;
      }
  product*=num;
while (input.hasNextInt()) {
    num = input.nextInt();
    if (num < 1)
        break;
    product *= num;
}
```